# I think this data should be analysed using a linear mixed-effects model, but it doesn't seem to make sense when using buildmer?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I can't give the exact data because it's sensitive, but I have the following information about the data:

- 3 continuous variables which are within subjects (scores for test separated by time).
- 1 categorical variable with 4 levels which are between subjects (condition).
- 1 continuous dependent variable (average test score not divided by time).

I want to find out whether test scores over time (my 3 continuous within-subject variables) are significantly different from each other and whether this effect is moderated by the condition that the test was taken in (my categorical between-subject variable).

I assumed the best way to do this was by using a linear mixed effects model in R, with the code shown here:

```
lmer(dep_variable ~ cont_ind_variable_1*condition + cont_ind_variable_2*condition + cont_ind_variable_3*condition + (1 | Subject), data=data)
```

However, I assume this model is too complex for the data, since I get the following error message:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: ID)
```

So, I used the `buildmer` package to simplify my maximal model to reduce the number of observations, like this:

```
buildmer::buildmer(dep_variable ~ cont_ind_variable_1*condition + cont_ind_variable_2*condition + cont_ind_variable_3*condition + (1 | Subject), data=data)
```

But my output suggests cutting the random intercepts for subject, which I don't think makes sense since subjects are repeated across continuous variables, just not across my categorical variable:

```
Call:
stats::lm(formula = dep_variable ~ 1 + cont_ind_variable_1 + 
    cont_ind_variable_2 + cont_ind_variable_3 + condition + 
    cont_ind_variable_3:condition + cont_ind_variable_1:condition + 
    condition:cont_ind_variable_2, data = data)
```

I'm not too familiar with linear mixed effects models, but there seems to be something off about what I'm trying to do and I can't put my finger on it? Do I need to aggregate data or something like that?

Comment: Sorry to ask such basic questions, but just to make sure, do you have several (3?) observations per participant for your dependent variable and is your data in long format (i.e. as many rows for participant as there are observations per participant)? Also, what is the name of your participant id signifier in your data?

Comment: Yes this is a good question I've just realised that I don't. My dependent variable only has 1 observation per ppt, but my data is in short format. The name of my ppt ID signifier is 'subject'

Comment: OK, but you have 3 observations (from 3 time points) per participant? If so, just convert your data in long format. In R, you can do it easily via tidyr package function pivot_longer. Then use your long format dataframe in lmer, that should work :)

Comment: Ahh ok I see, so how would I code a linear mixed-effects model if my data was in long format? Sorry I'm not good at stats and I only ever use wide format data before

Comment: Your lmer code is fine, you just need to get your dataset into long format so that each participant has 3 rows (if you have 3 time points) and there is one variable/column indicating values of your dependent variable, one variable/column indicating the values of your time-varying predictor variable etc.

Comment: ...though I noticed it's not that easy to convert data with multiple sets of variables (here, your dependent variable and your time-varying predictors) in pivot_longer, I usually do that in SPSS.

Comment: There are reasons not to use random effects for longitudinal data as discussed [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re).  And the best tools for restructuring data are based on the `data.table` package as covered [here](https://hbiostat.org/rflow).  See the chapter on manipulating longitudinal data.

Comment: The goal of testing “statistical significance” needs to be much better thought out, as this means very little.  Best to think of what you want to estimate, then estimate it, and include uncertainties for the estimates.

Comment: Thank you Frank for you input. In that case, would you suggest that I analyse the data by using a simple linear regression with 'condition' as my moderating factor?

Comment: Also @Sointu when I convert my data to long format, the buildmer function in R still recommends that I do not include random intercepts for my subject variable?

Comment: I don't know buildmer, but one reason for this may be that participant-specific variance in your outcome is very close to zero, so the function tells you random intercept is not needed.

Comment: I think this may be why, do you happen to know how I could check my data to see if this was the case? If this is the cause, do you think it's just a case of needing to run a simple linear regression with 'condition' as my moderating factor?

Comment: You should be able to tell from model output (if you run it in lmer, check the Random effects Variance - if that's very small, this is likely the reason). And yes, I'd probably use single-level regression in this case, maybe with robust standard errors.

Comment: The links in the comments by @FrankHarrell provide a wealth of information about (a) mixed effects modeling generally and (b) efficient manipulation of data using the `data.table` package.  It's worth anybody's time to study both.

Answer (score 2):

##### Programming Side

The issue afoot here is the following error code, which was already noted by Sointu:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: ID)
```

It appears in the data's current form, you do not have multiple observations per subject ID, hence the error and the lack of fitting. This is likely also why the `buildmer` package asked to remove the random intercepts (or a lack of random intercept variance as suggested in the comments). I'm not sure how that particularly package works beyond the random effects selection outlined in the vignette, but I'm guessing this is a safeguard against you fitting a random effects model that you can't actually use.

##### Modeling

As Frank suggested, you probably don't even need a mixed model here.
The reason you don't want to just use random effects here is that it doesn't really address the "forward march of time"...the random variation is captured by the model, but it doesn't properly address *how* that variation shifts by time point.

Given you only have three time points, a fixed effects regression can handle that fine, though that will depend on how you want to model time. Simply adding time in as a main effect would at least eliminate any correlated errors here, which is one of the reasons people use mixed models in the first place. You could look at how it interacts with your other effects here, but be careful of including complex interactions willy nilly, as interactions are usually weak by nature, and more complex interactions may amplify this issue.

Comment: Thank you Shawn this is incredibly helpful! Just to clarify, a fixed effects regression with moderation for condition may be the best way to analyse this data? I was thinking about conducting a MANOVA with post-hoc tests since I could analyse multiple dependent variables simultaneously - could that also be appropriate in this context?

Comment: I don't see the multiple DVs here, but I am also personally not a fan of MANOVA for reasons outlined [here](https://quantitudepod.org/s2e09-manova-must-die/). If you want to do something with multiple DVs, you could consider structural equation modeling instead, but that requires a lot of reading.